# Use Laravel factories to set 'default' values for new models?

Tags: laravel, factories

I have always thought of Laravel factories as a 'development' aid for generating fake data for testing purposes.

Recently, I inherited a Laravel 8 project where this is used in part for that, but it is also called from the production code to essentially insert 'default data' for a new entity that is being created.

(Think: We're creating a Company::class, and so we're going to also create blank contact profiles (CompanyContact::class) for its 'president', 'vice-president', and 'treasurer' with some basic placeholder text.)

That obviously *works* but when trying to determine where this default data was even coming from, it never occurred to me to look in database seeders/factories.

I would rather have expected to see a "created" event responder, either setup in Model::boot() or as a standalone event.

Aside from confusing future developers (or just me?), are there any other gotchas to using (misusing?) factory methods as a means of setting up 'default data'?

Answer (score 0):

I got used to seeding the website settings or even some default data like Countries by using Seeders.

Of course, triggering events when seeding these data will be a good solution, but also I think the simple solution is leaving the created_at column null to determine the source of the data.

Comment: Those examples make sense to me, because they are one-time things that happen when setting up a new DB or site. This, however, occurs every time a new 'transaction' is created. It is essentially like default DB values, except that because it happens across multiple related models, a bit more is needed.